# My delete key won't work in Eclipse in OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard

My delete key isn't working in Eclipse in OS X.  However, Shift-Delete deletes.

Delete works elsewhere, so a setting must have been unwittingly changed.  Any idea what it is or how to fix it?

Restarting Eclipse didn't help.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263921/really-weird-eclipse-keyboard-problem-bug/5585512

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check your key mapping for delete and cut commands:

[image: cut and delete key mapping preferences]

Maybe the delete key has been re-affected.

Comment: Strange.  The binding was displayed correctly, but the problem disappeared when I unbound and restored the delete command.  Thanks much.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too. Note to anyone else who may come across this: I had to restart Eclipse for it to take effect.

Comment: Solved this problem on OS X by putting the computer in sleep mode and then waking it up. everything was back to normal. It's an eclipse bug.

Answer (score 6):

I'm on a mac and this is a trip. None of the answers are working for me. I tried everything suggested here :(

I was about to reinstall eclipse and decided to see if a restart would help. I logged off...

```
 | Log out [user]
```

and then logged back on and I got control of my arrows and delete key again.

!!! UPDATE !!! If I close one program in the doc I get it all back.

This generally happens to me when Firefox Crashes

Comment: Similar thing for me. I'm also on a Mac, and this has been happening to me occasionally for at least 1.5 years. Eclipse Indigo and Juno are definitely affected, not sure anymore about Helios. Happened on Snow Leopard, Lion, and Mountain Lion.

The only workaround I've found so far is to restart Eclipse.

Comment: I figured it out. When Firefox crashes I lose many keys, delete, escape, arrows, etc... I figured out that if I close one program on the doc I get everything back. Choose a program... Doesn't matter.

Comment: Strange! It happened to me as well. Firefox crashed. Delete key stopped working. Closed a program (picked a random one) and tested and Delete key started working again! BAM!

Comment: @1.21gigawatts I added this as another answer since it appears to be relevant. ;) thanks.

Comment: lol that's madness.  Happened to me too, and the fix worked.  "Oh your eclipse bugged out.. simple, it's because your browser crashed and the fix is to close any other unrelated program".  Awesome.

Comment: @Jason you're cracking me up :D

Answer (score 4):

I have this problem with Helios too sometimes. It seems like it has to do with changing focus to another app and when i return, the arrow keys and delete don't work. If you also have problems with the arrow keys, the solution is to change the

```
Preferences | General | Keys | Scheme
```

I just change it to something and change it back and it solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**STRANGE SOLUTION WORKS! Recover by randomly closing one program in the Mac dock**

Pick any program in the dock and close it. This usually happens to me when Firefox crashes, but it might work for you as well.

Added this as an alternative answer because it appears to be relevant —Shanimal

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers help me. It works after following actions:

- Go to Preference > General > Keys > Delete
- Clear Binding text field
- Assign Tab to Binding text field, then click OK (it works as press tab to delete files)
- Go back Preference > General > Keys > Delete
- Clear Binding text field
- Assign "Delete" to Binding text field, then click OK

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

This was a known bug in previous (non-Helios -- 3.6) versions of Eclipse. Apparently, the bug was addressed in Helios:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=283415

Answer (score 1):

Hi Fn key and delete works for me.

What I did I clear the binding and Apply 
Then I again set the binding and Apply.
Then Restart the Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem too. Got the delete key to work again by right clicking one of the tabs I had open in eclipse and clicking "Close All"

Somehow that worked.

Someone mentioned it generally happens after firefox crashes, oddly enough that did happen after my firefox crashed.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem here using Mac OSX 10.7.5 and Eclipse 4.2.2
loosing DEL Key, Save Shortcut (and maybe others)

Solution for me is to click into another file-editor window and back into the one i was editing.