# Eclipse stopped recognizing my Kinesis keyboard shortcut buttons(copy, paste, etc)?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard, eclipse-rcp

I have a [Kinesis Freestyle](http://www.thehumansolution.com/kinesis-freestyle.html?utm_source=Google%2BShopping&utm_medium=cpc&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Google%2BShopping&gdftrk=gdfV2929_a_7c132_a_7c5187_a_7cKIN700&gclid=CKuW5eG76bcCFeNj7Aod8RoA0w) keyboard which has keys for common shortcuts (ie a cut, copy, etc buttons).

However, for the last few days Eclipse has stopped receiving the keyboard buttons correctly, and even CTRL+X is not working. One button("Paste") is actually registering as a page-down instead.

But the keyboard buttons/shortcuts work fine in Chrome and in Windows.

Does anyone have a clue about this?

Comment: Did you try to use a new workspace?

Comment: @Kane - Wowsas! it worked!!!!! tyvm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to solve it: switch workspace, or "Restore Defaults" in the `Preferences -> Keys` menu

[image]

You can also switched workspace , that's what i did first, and everything worked fine again( i guess bec. I didn't fiddle with keys & shortcuts).

```
File->Switch Workspace
```

Apparently, based on this SO link - [really weird eclipse keyboard behavior/bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263921/really-weird-eclipse-keyboard-behavior-bug) - it may be a configuration issue that is workspace-dependent(maybe a custom keyboard shortcut I added-on ??!?).

I'm still curious about a way to narrow down why, but it looks like a clash of the key-bindings.

Here's another link, [Switching workspaces](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-workspaceswitch.htm)