# Eclipse juno function bug in ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am using Eclipse Juno in an Ubuntu environment, and about every hour my eclipse functions start to act weird. Pressing `delete, Ctrl-d` will stop working, or delete things in another class I have opened.

Same thing for the cut/paste and inspect functionality, it either doesn't do anything or it pastes/inspects something in a different class I have opened. I doesn't matter if I try it by using the mouse or the keyboard shortcuts.

I'm fairly sure it's an eclipse issue, as this only affects eclipse, and when I restart eclipse these issues are resolved. This is a pain in the ass though, as I have multiple servers running in eclipse, and restarting these take some time.

Refreshing my project as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263921/really-weird-eclipse-keyboard-behavior-bug) doesn't work for me.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

sounds like your key bindings might be being overridden by a plugin you have installed..\

Open eclipse, go to -

```
Window->Preferences->General->Keys
```

filter for `Delete Line`- if it is not bound to <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> then set the binding.

To check for duplicates, click the `Delete Line` key binding, then sort by "Binding" and see if you have one overriding it.  If you do, then you have a couple options -

1. Disable the <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> binding that the plugin is using
2. Change your `Delete Line` binding to another.  I like mine being <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>

The way keybindings work in eclipse is all dependent on the `When` column in the key bindings window.  It **should** be set to `Editing Text`   - if it's not, then you should probably set it to that.  It might not be working for you in some other content type, say, if you are editing the `.classpath`

Comment: I'm not experiencing the problem at the moment, but when I go to check my keybindings I see that almost all of them are duplicate. One for 'Editing Text', and one for 'Embedded Xtext Editor context'. If I experience the problem later today I will erase the Xtext one to see if it works. Thx!

Comment: I'm experiencing the problem now, and instead of appearing 2 times, Ctrl+d appeared 3 times. The When column specified 'in windows category'. Removing this binding did not work however..

Comment: Did you restart eclipse after you assured that only 1 Ctrl+d was assigned?

Comment: after I noticed reassigning the keys did not work, I restarted eclipse. Afterwards it worked like it should work again